# Как отредактировать страницу с уже готовым заказом пользователя woocomerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

[image: Пример с сайта, что нужно отредактировать]

В общих чертах, встала задача отредактировать данную страницу. Залил в папку woocomerce кастомные файлы myaccount, и там как раз есть view-order.php, но когда меняю там какие-либо данные, все равно не та страница, которую мне нужно отредактировать. Пожалуйста, помогите

Comment: https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-checkout-page/

Comment: Это же к странице checkout, а не к личному кабинету

Comment: Это  один из мануалов  по хукам.